# Local translation symfony

Tags: symfony, yaml

i have problem in my logout , it wont detect the local language and return the default one
here is the firewall

```
        logout:
            path:   logout
            target: /%locale%/Siivt/
```

and here is the root

```
        logout:
            pattern:   /{_locale}/Deconnection
```

it always return the fr local while the connexion work fine
to be more clear when i navigate in the english version of my site , after loging off it return the site in the french local i want that it keep the local

Comment: I don't think it would be logical to have different versions of logout functionality in one project, like `Logout from English version` or `Logout from Russian`, better configure it without `locale`..

Answer (score 0):

It is because `%locale%` point to default locale that you configured in `parameters.yml`.

If your `%locale%` (default locale) equals to `fr` then your route will be `fr/Siivt` always.

To solve your problem I would recommend you to store `locale` in the session and generate all urls independent of current locale. And make some controller that will switch your locale and return back to last viewed page.